# Can't tf get from command line but can get latest from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

When I type `tf get` in a command line from the root directory of my local workspace mapping, I get the error:

```
TF30063: You are not authorized to access [server\collection]
```

When I do a Get Latest through Visual Studio, it pulls down the latest files.

What could be causing this?  Do I need to sign in from the command line somehow?

Comment: Are you specifying the correct server & collection?

Comment: are you using the same User from visual studio and the cmd?

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect, map workspace and use command line tools, a little change must be made at the user's visualstudio.com profile settings. This change is concerning CREDENTIALS. Alternate Authentication Credentials (AAC) must be first enabled and then a password must be defined in order to make such kind of access available. The original email address may be used to access from 
command line tools but alternatively a second email or alias can be defined in order to make it work.

This configuration can be made at the visualstudio.com website. After you signed in, go to your profile settings. At the superior left corner, select Security, and then at the left side bar, select Alternate Authentication Credentials. Setup your new credential and use it to make the commands work.

Basic commands list website: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873092.aspx